# Modify only the subject and send the draft

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-api

I know how to [send a Gmail draft with](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-draft):

```
var draft = GmailApp.getDrafts()[0]; 
var msg = draft.send();
```

and how to modify the draft with [`update`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-draft#update(String,String,String)):

```
draft.update("mike@example.com", "current time", "The time hello")
```

**But how to *modify the subject only* and not the content, not the attachments (if any), not the recipient?**

Comment: the gmail api has setters for each individually https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/drafts but the apps script api doesnt seem to have those... strange, did you try setters anyways? even though they arent listed in the api?

Comment: Thank you @Erch, do you mean `email.setSubject(subject);`?

Comment: either that or on the draf directly, its a long shot though, since in the api there are no such setters

Comment: @Erch `TypeError: Cannot find function setSubject in object GmailMessage`, same in object `GmailDraft`.

Comment: mhh no suprise tbh, i think there is now way, but to store the values from creating the mail somewhere and reusing them in the update

Comment: @Erch The goal is to send a draft via API at a certain date, that has been manually created by the user on www.gmail.com. I'd like to modify only the subject of the draft, but keep the original content, keep the HTML if any, keep the attachment if any, etc.

Comment: doesnt seem to be possible atm, you may want to create a ticket for it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- You want to update only the subject of draft.
- You don't want to modify the text body, HTML body and attachment files.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this sample script? I think that there are several answers. So please think of this as just one of them.

In this sample script, I used Class GmailApp and Gmail API. The flow of script is as follows.

1. Retrieve raw data of draft as a text using Class GmailApp.
2. Replace the subject of the raw data.
3. Convert the text to base64 using `Utilities.base64EncodeWebSafe()`.
4. Update the draft using new raw data by Gmail API.

By this flow, only subject can be updated.

**Before you run this script, please enable Gmail API at Advanced Google Services and API console.**

### Enable Gmail API v1 at Advanced Google Services

- On script editor

  - Resources -> Advanced Google Services
  - Turn on Gmail API v1

### Enable Gmail API at API console

- On script editor

  - Resources -> Cloud Platform project
  - View API console
  - At Getting started, click "Explore and enable APIs".
  - At left side, click Library.
  - At Search for APIs & services, input "Gmail". And click Gmail API.
  - Click Enable button.
  - If API has already been enabled, please don't turn off.

### Sample script:

```
function updateDraftmail() {
  var newSubject = "new subject"; // Please set new subject.
  var userId = "me"; // Please set userId.
  var draft = GmailApp.getDrafts()[0]; // Retrieve a draft.

  var raw = draft.getMessage().getRawContent();
  var newRaw = raw.replace(/Subject: \w.+/, "Subject: " + newSubject);
  var newRawB64 = Utilities.base64EncodeWebSafe(newRaw, Utilities.Charset.UTF_8);
  Gmail.Users.Drafts.update({message: {raw: newRawB64}}, userId, draft.getId());
}
```

### References :

- [getRawContent()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#getRawContent())
- [base64EncodeWebSafe()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#base64encodewebsafedata_2)
- [Advanced Google Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced)
- [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/)
- [Users.drafts: update](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/drafts/update)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not what you want, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you very much @Tanaike. Just a sidenote: in my real code what should be instead of `var userId = "me"; // Please set userId.`? My email like that: `myaddress@gmail.com`? Or an ID (to be found where?)

Comment: @Basj Thank you for replying. You can use both ``me`` and your email as ``userId``. For example, you can also see the document about ``userId`` at [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/drafts/list).