# Apps Script Gmail createDraftReplyAll wrong recipient: Puts me as recipient instead of other party

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

I have a working script for creating a new Gmail draft but when I use `createDraftReplyAll` in an existing thread, it puts the sender of the last email of the thread as the recipient of the draft.

So if I sent the last email, I become the recipient of the reply, and the other party is Cc'd. And if the other person wrote the last email, they are the recipient but I get CC'd. This is not normal behavior compared with manually creating a draft in Gmail (i.e. from clicking Reply To All), in which case the recipient will always be the other party.

Shown here (result of running the script below):

[image]

And normal behavior from clicking Reply All in Gmail:

[image]

This is the function I use to create the draft. The thread has already been found via the Subject and original message date:

```
  function createDraftReplyInThread(emailThread, htmlTemplateFileName) {
  Logger.log(">> IN createDraftReplyInThread");
  Logger.log("htmlTemplateFileName: " + htmlTemplateFileName);

  if (emailThread) {
    let emailTo = emailThread.to;
    Logger.log('Thread TO: ' + emailTo);
    let threadMessages = emailThread.getMessages();
    let messageCount = threadMessages.length;
    let lastMessage = threadMessages[messageCount - 1];

    let htmlTemplate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(htmlTemplateFileName);
    let htmlBodyContent = htmlTemplate.evaluate().getContent();
    var myReplyID = lastMessage.createDraftReplyAll(
      "Plain text for draft reply (not used)",
      {
        'htmlBody': htmlBodyContent
      }).getId();

    Logger.log(`Draft created in thread; myReplyID: ${myReplyID}`);  // just to show it's executed okay

    return;
  }

  return null;
}
```

It's probably best to ignore this, but I did try to use the limited existing update methods to copy the content, change the recipient and reinstate the the content in a new draft (pure guess work). Noting that draft.update() does work to change the recipient but it also requires a Message argument which I failed to get to work. Possible?

```
// based off stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54745999/modify-only-the-subject-and-send-the-draft
function _sandbox_draftModify() {

  var draft = GmailApp.getDrafts()[0];
  var draftAsMessage = draft.getMessage();
  var recipients = draftAsMessage.getTo();
  var subject = draftAsMessage.getSubject();
  var origRaw = draftAsMessage.getRawContent();
  var newRaw = origRaw.replace("new draft", "old draft");
  var newRawB64 = Utilities.base64EncodeWebSafe(newRaw, Utilities.Charset.UTF_8);

  var emailTo = 'recipientsemail@gmail.com';  
  Logger.log(`recipients: ${recipients}`);
  Logger.log(`subject: ${subject}`);
  Logger.log(`newRaw: ${newRaw}`);

  draft.update(emailTo, subject, { message: { raw: newRawB64 } });

  var draftNew = GmailApp.getDrafts()[0];
  userId = 'me';
  Gmail.Users.Drafts.update({ message: { raw: newRawB64 } }, userId, draftNew.getId());
  Logger.log("Done");
}
```

In the end all I need is to be able to create a draft email to an existing thread (which I can do already) but *with the correct recipient(s)*, however that may be achieved.

Comment: This looks something for the Google Apps Script issue tracker rather than a question for other programmers. Are you looking for a workaround? P.S. I don't know the reason of the first downvote.

Comment: Thx for the feedback. If is bugged there is perhaps hope in a workaround with the draft.update() method (from which the recipient can be changed - perfect!) but it needs a message too, but the message already exists which is why I tried to copy the message body from the existing draft, then use Gmail.Users.Drafts.update to restore the content ( based off of the SO thread linked to). It also needs a Subject, but that's no problem as it can be taken from the existing draft and is just a sting. I don't know how to put the copied message body into the appropriate format. I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This seems to be the expected behavior for the `createDraftReplyAll` method.**

If you check the documentation page here:

> `createDraftReplyAll(body)`
>
> Creates a draft message replying **to the sender of the last message in this thread**, using the reply-to address and all recipients of this message. The size of the email (including headers) is quota limited.

However, you can file a feature request on Issue Tracker if you would like to have a functionality which replicates the UI behavior. The form can be found at this [link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191640&template=824113) and make sure to fill in all the necessary information.

#### Reference

- [Apps Script GmailThread Class - createDraftReplyAll()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-thread#createdraftreplyallbody).

Comment: So true. I have to wonder what use case they had in mind, given that when you're the last writer in the thread the email would get sent to oneself with the other party CC'd and when the other party is the last writer they (correctly) would get emailed but you get a CC'd email in your Inbox. Seems bizarre but thank you for helping out here.

Answer (score 1):

Your objective wasn't too clear to me but I assume the behavior you want to achieve is to have the recipient and cc(s) to be populated as per their values in the email thread (without your own email address appearing in the cc list)

I was able to achieve it in the following way:

```
/**
 *  Get all unique recipients besides for self
 */

function getAllRecipientsOfMessage(message) {

  const ccList = message.getCc().split(",");
  const toList = message.getTo().split(",");
  const result = ccList.concat(toList)
  const uniqueResult = Array.from(new Set(result));

  return uniqueResult.filter(function(value) {
   return !value.includes(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail());
 });

/**
 *  Creates a draft email
 */

function insertDraft(message) {

  var draft = message.createDraftReply('Reply text', {
    cc: getAllRecipientsOfMessage(message).join(','),
    replyTo: message.getFrom()
  });

  return CardService.newComposeActionResponseBuilder().setGmailDraft(draft).build()
}
```